# Height auto doesn't work even with clearfix

Tags: html, css

Probably not the first time you see this question... but I can't solve this problem.

Here is live version 
 http://jsfiddle.net/LndEh/

If you change height for `.projectwrap`, you will see what I am trying to achieve. I have tried add clearfix etc.

**HTML**

```
<div class="projectwrap">
<img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/superman-logo-012.png">
<div class="inner"><a href=""><span>sometext</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="projectwrap">
<img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/superman-logo-012.png">
<div class="inner"><a href=""><span>some text</span></a></div>
</div>

 <div class="projectwrap">
 <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/superman-logo-012.png">
<div class="inner"><a href=""><span>some text</span></a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.projectwrap
{
position: relative; 
width: 28%;
height:auto;
float:left;
}
.projectwrap img
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}

.inner
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(http://goodlogo.com/images/logos/batman_logo_2574.gif);
background-size: cover;
position:absolute;
z-index: 11;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
-o-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
transition: opacity 400ms linear;
}
.inner a
{
float:left;
text-align: center;
display:table;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}
.inner a span
{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width:100%;
height:100%;
color:#fff;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.inner:hover
{
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
-o-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
transition: opacity 400ms linear;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve or what the problem is. Possible to clarify?

Comment: as i mentioned, in css for .projectwrap, change height from auto to some value, example 100px. Update fiddle and u will see. Main problem is: all 3 divs are without height, so images are top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the containers are floated and contain absolutely positioned images, they have no height and will float over each other.

If you want all three logos to appear, change the CSS for the images to `position:relative`

```
.projectwrap img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LndEh/1/

**EDIT:**

Another method, if you need to use `position:absolute` on the images:

Set a minimum height for the `.projectwrap` divs so that they don't collapse to zero height.
Then they will float as expected.

```
.projectwrap {
    position: relative;
    width:28%;
    float:left;
    min-height:5px;height:auto!important;height:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LndEh/2/

**EDIT:**

For the additional three (hidden) images, I have changed from using a background image to using the same 100% width method you used for the superman logos. I placed the links over the image by positioning them absolutely.

```
.inner {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
.inner a {
    position:absolute;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LndEh/3/

**EDIT:**

I think I see now what you're going for.
I switched from using `background-image` on `.inner` to using `<img />` and kept your elements positioned absolutely. Does that work better?

http://jsfiddle.net/LndEh/7/

Comment: You probably didn't saw what i try to accomplish here. I have div with images, i need that absolute positioning so image can be 100% width against this div ( which is positioned relative ) . Inside that div i have another div, which is also positioned absolute and 100%width/height. This inner div has background image with opacity 0 . On hover opacity sets to value. As i said, please change height from auto to some value. Hover those images and u will see what i need. Maybe i am doing thighs wrong here.

Comment: No, I didn't. (It would be helpful if you explain your issue in its entirety.) It seems that you want `.inner` to expand the height of `.projectwrap` but also inherit height from `.projectwrap`. That is a paradox. I edited my answer with another method -- maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Sorry for not providing all information.
But still , batmen logos ar under superman logos. 

Long story short- i want create div, like gallery, when hovering it becomes darker and title appears. So i used another div like "mask", which is visible when hovered, with background opacity set to <1. Except , i have texture instead of just background-color:black.

For example http://www.graftik.lv/en/portfolio . Hover on images

Comment: Cool! One thing I notice is that it messes up your `table-cell` vertical centering. Maybe because the `<a>` is positioned absolutely. Tricky one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36742/discussion-between-merkley-and-showdev)